# Is there a way to replace a string with html tags in TWIG (Symfony2)?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have an html saved in my database with a special tag string like [special_tag] and I want to display that html to my twig template at the same time replace the [special_tag] with any html elements.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you could use Twig's [`replace` filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/replace.html):

```
{{ my_variable_with_html | replace({'[special_tag]': 'new value'}) }}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response but I've already tried that.
{% set var_html = "[special_tag]"%}
{{ var_html|replace({"[special_tag]": "<p>new value</p>" }) }}

result: <p>new value</p>
expected: new value

Comment: You'll have to add another filter: [`raw`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/raw.html): `{{ var_html | replace(...) | raw }}`

Comment: No! You shouldn't use `raw` here as it breaks your security. `raw` allows HTML content in `var_html`.